# Indexes and Owned Types

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have searched and searched, and I believe I know the answer.  But I'm asking, just to make sure...

I have been creating Owned Types in my EF Core 2.0 models, and working through the... quirks so far.  My current issue is creating an index that includes one or more properties from my owned type inside of another entity.

Essentially, as far as I can tell, the owned type is running into the same issue as trying to index on a navigation property (and, BTW, *awesome* job MS choosing exception text that tells you nothing about the actual problem...).  However, with navigation properties, you can resort to the string-name version and reference the shadow property.  I have had no luck trying that with owned types - it appears EF doesn't create "shadow properties" for them.  Referencing the actual column name errors out because it's not a defined property name on the model (and would appear to confirm my "no shadow properties" thought); and `nameof` doesn't work with sub-objects, and would probably give the wrong name anyway.

So what I have resorted to is creating indexes with the Fluent API using as many of the columns as I can, and then adding the additional columns I need directly in the migration script.  While it works, this is, for reasons I hope are obvious, sub-optimal.

So what am I missing?  I *really* want to use owned types, but given the "Vortex Of Renaming Death" on migrations and now this, I'm getting close to saying "screw it", pulling them out, and re-doing them manually, if for no other reason than to avoid ire from the rest of my team.  Obviously this is a relatively new feature, but I am struggling to understand why it was released in the state it's in...

Comment: Thanks for mentioning your workaround - I'm now using it, too. I'm guessing the Owned Types are designed somewhat like their own Entities in the restrictions for the time being, but I'm hopeful that as more support is added for other storage types (like Graph databases), support for this gets included for the Relational databases, too!

Comment: There is an issue on github for this: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11336 In the chat there is also a workaround provided using shaddow properties. Although I don't really like it and waiting until the issue will be fixed.

Answer (score 17):

you can define index for owned types, tried with EF core 2.1 preview 2

```
public class MainEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MainEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MainEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable(nameof(MainEntity));
        builder.Ignore(b => b.DomainEvents);

        builder.HasKey(x => x.MainEntityId);
        builder.HasIndex(x => x.AnyPropFromMainEntity);

        builder.OwnsOne(x => x.ValueObjectInsideMainEntity, xx =>
        {
            xx.HasIndex(o => o.ValueObjectsProp);
            xx.Property(o => o.ValueObjectsProp2).HasMaxLength(256);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution only works if you use property from within owned type, but for example if you wish to add properties to the index from outside of `ValueObjectInsideMainEntity` you would face issues.

Comment: This is specially a problem if you are using nested owned types...